# Drools Error with readKnowledgebase

Tags: drools

I'm trying a very basic rule to test if drools works , I connected it with hibernate , yet I find the error " java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1" 
this is the main :
package metier;

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import metier.environnements.Reseau;

import org.drools.KnowledgeBase;
import org.drools.KnowledgeBaseFactory;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilder;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderError;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderErrors;
import org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory;
import org.drools.builder.ResourceType;
import org.drools.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLogger;
import org.drools.logger.KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory;
import org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import util.HibernateUtil;



/* This is a sample class to launch a rule. */

public class testingRules {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session =HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();



        Query query=session.createQuery("from Reseau");
        List l =query.list();
        Iterator reseaux = query .iterate();

        while (reseaux.hasNext()) {

        Reseau reseau = (Reseau) reseaux.next();

        // Set the process start arguments.


        StatefulKnowledgeSession sks = getSKS();
        sks.insert(reseau);
        sks.fireAllRules();
}

session.getTransaction().commit();



    }

    /**
     * Creates a basic {@link StatefulKnowledgeSession} which contains the <code>BPMN2</code> process definition of our sample process.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private static StatefulKnowledgeSession getSKS() {
        KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
        kbuilder.add(
                ResourceFactory
                        .newClassPathResource("Reseau.drl"),
                ResourceType.DRL);
        KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();

        return kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
    }

    }
```

and the .drl file is :

```
package metier.environnements

import metier.taches.ActiviteProfessionnelle;
import metier.taches.Utilisateur;



rule "Réseaux_disponibles"  // donne les réseaux disponibles dans la localisation de l'utilisateur
ruleflow-group "networks"
    when
      reseau :  Reseau (reseau.getCle() == "mot")
    then
        System.out.println ("Réseaux disponibles");

end
```

the error that appears is :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeCastExpressionWithNameArray(Parser.java:1984)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeRule(Parser.java:5992)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9272)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9500)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9457)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:8102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:420)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:389)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:371)
    at org.drools.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:46)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:102)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:1006)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAllRules(PackageBuilder.java:842)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:831)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:467)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:673)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:45)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:34)
    at metier.testingRules.getSKS(testingRules.java:66)
    at metier.testingRules.main(testingRules.java:48)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeCastExpressionWithNameArray(Parser.java:1984)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.consumeRule(Parser.java:5992)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9272)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9500)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:9457)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.dietParse(Parser.java:8102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:420)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:389)
    at org.drools.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:371)
    at org.drools.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:46)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:102)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:1006)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAllRules(PackageBuilder.java:842)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:831)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:467)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:673)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:45)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:34)
    at metier.testingRules.getSKS(testingRules.java:66)
    at metier.testingRules.main(testingRules.java:48)
```

Do you have any idea where it comes from and how I can fix it ? 
I would really appreciate it

```
the class Reseau definition is : 
package metier.environnements;

public class Reseau {

    private Long idReseau;
    private String nom; 
    private String cle;//mot de passe  
    private String etat ;  // disponible ou non 
    private String vitesseTransfert;  //speed
    private String type ; // 3G , LTE , Wifi ...
    private Localisation  localisation;

    // Les getters and setters.

    public Long getIdReseau() {
        return idReseau;
    }


    public void setIdReseau(Long idReseau) {
        this.idReseau = idReseau;
    }


    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }


    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }


    public String getCle() {
        return cle;
    }


    public void setCle(String cle) {
        this.cle = cle;
    }


    public String getEtat() {
        return etat;
    }


    public void setEtat(String etat) {
        this.etat = etat;
    }


    public String getVitesseTransfert() {
        return vitesseTransfert;
    }


    public void setVitesseTransfert(String vitesseTransfert) {
        this.vitesseTransfert = vitesseTransfert;
    }


    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }


    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


    public Localisation getLocalisation() {
        return localisation;
    }


    public void setLocalisation(Localisation localisation) {
        this.localisation = localisation;
    }



    // Constructeur par defaut  

    public Reseau() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // Le constructeur avec les champs , le id sera genere automatiquement  
    public Reseau(String nom, String cle, String etat, String vitesseTransfert,
            String type, Localisation localisation) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.cle = cle;
        this.etat = etat;
        this.vitesseTransfert = vitesseTransfert;
        this.type = type;
        this.localisation = localisation;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never call the DRL compiler without checking for errors:

```
kbuilder.add(..., ResourceType.DRL);
if( kbuilder.hasErrors() ){
    System.err.println( "### compilation errors ###" );
    KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kbuilder.getErrors();
    for( KnowledgeBuilderError err: errors ){
        System.err.println( err.toString() );
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException( "compile errors" );
}
```

But the problem looks like an error in the DRL/Java parsing step. Which Drools version are you using? And the definition of class Reseau would be necessary to reproduce the error.

Errors in old (5.x) Drools versions aren't likely to get fixed. Try 6.2.

Comment: I'm using Drools 5.4.0 , I added the definition of the class Reseau in the post .
thank you for your help ..

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, even with 5.4.0. But I don't compile from within Eclipse. Try in a shell using this classpath: `root=/extra/drools-distribution-5.4.0.Final/binaries;` `tag=5.4.0.Final;` `export CLASSPATH=.:$root/drools-core-${tag}.jar:$root/knowledge-api-${tag}.jar:$root/knowledge-internal-api-${tag}.jar:$root/drools-compiler-${tag}.jar:$root/antlr-2.7.7.jar:$root/antlr-3.3.jar:$root/antlr-runtime-3.3.jar:$root/ecj-3.5.1.jar:$root/mvel2-2.1.0.drools16.jar:/extra/quartz-1.8.3/quartz-1.8.3.jar:$root/drools-decisiontables-${tag}.jar:$root/drools-templates-${tag}.jar:$root/jxl-2.6.10.jar`

Comment: I upgraded to Drools 6.2 like you recommended , yet the problem persisted , so I opened a new Drools project and copy-pasted everything , the error doesn't appear anymore but there is nothing displayed . 
PS : when I execute the rule without using hibernate it works and when I don't use Drools and simply print the objects from Hibernate it works too but there is nothing displayed when I combine both ..  
What seems to be the problem ?? I really can't understand that

Comment: I don't see how the group `ruleflow-group "networks"` is activated in the code you have provided. - Add Reseau.toString and print the result before the insert. - Use a simple rule testing for `$r: Reseau()` and print `$r.toString` in the consequence.

Comment: Thank you so much !! It finally works , when I tried to print $r.toString , it displayed the class within the package : metier.environnements.Reseau@452451ba 
so when I used the getter in the rule , it worked and displayed the right output .. Thank you so much :) 
As for the ruleflow-group , yes I still haven't written the code in the knowledgebase to activate the flow , but I have it ready , I hope I won't get a problem with it when I try to .. Thanks again